# Excel text function specifying language/LCID

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, regional-settings

As seen on [this page](http://excel.tips.net/T003299_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html) and [this page](http://excelunplugged.com/2015/02/24/learn-a-foreign-language-with-excel/), it should be possible to specify the language used for date parsing with the text function in Excel cells.

Is there any special trick to get this working?

I have tried both these ways, can you see what may be wrong with it?

[image: First screenshot LCID after]

[image: Second screenshot LCID before]

My Excel version is 15.0.4805.1001 and the regional setting is German (Switzerland)

Comment: Interesting with `=TEXT(A1,"[$-40C]dddd mmmm yyyy")` I get `mardi juin 2016`

Comment: Using `=TODAY()` I get `mardi avril 2016` - cannot reproduce

Comment: Are you sure that `A1` is in `date` format?

Comment: @Raystafarian A1 is date format I think - the reason is that when I do ctrl-1 for format and change to general category - it shows 42535 which is the date value (from 1900).

Comment: Can you try it referencing `=today` or in a new workbook?

Comment: The format of the date is not recognized by excel as date, try using a type from the Format Cells under Category Date while selecting A1 and A2

Comment: @SuperSam changing A1 and A2 to date format didn't help I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is that when you specify the locality of the text conversion, you specify the locality of the output, not the locality of the parsing of the date format string.

Using German (Switzerland) means that the letter specifying day in the date is t, for month it is M, and for year it is j.

[image: first working]

[image: second working]